# `No "exports" main resolved ` error when trying to run Storybook

Tags: node.js, reactjs, babeljs, yarnpkg, storybook

I'm suddnely getting an error when running `yarn storybook` on my project. Storybook was working fine before, but suddenly stopped working giving me the errors:

This appears to be associated with Babel: ``No "exports" main resolved  /node_modules/@babel/helper-compilation-targets/package.json`

I've tried the following:

- Cleared yarn's cache
- Blew away `node_modules` and `package.json.lock` and reinstalled
- Reinstalled and updated node.js and NVM

But the issue keeps happening.

Would anyone know what I could do?

(ps I am on MacOs Mojave)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This turned out to be my local version of node.js conflicting with the packages in the project. I changed version to that indicated in the package and it seems to be working now.